Is there a way to automate generating an SSH key for git clone every time I spin up a new remote server?
Currently, every time I spin up a new remote server, I create a new SSH key and register it with my GitHub account to clone private repositories.
I believe using an SSH key is mandatory for this, but it feels inefficient to generate a new key each time. Can this be automated in some way?

Besides a CI/CD system fetching the repos once, building them, and then pushing the built content to all appropriate systems?

Yes Besides a CI/CD
